# SilverStripe - Custom Faceted Search Navigation

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, silverstripe

I'm working on page for a SilverStripe that will allow users to sort through portfolio pieces based on the selected facets.

Here are the key points/requirements:

- I have 2 facet categories they can search by: Media Type (i.e. Ads,
  Posters, TV, Web) and Industry (Entertainment, Finance, Healthcare,
  Sport, etc).
- Users should be allowed to search multiple facets at once and also
  across media type and industry at once.
- In the SilverStripe admin, since content managers **need** to be able
  to maintain the facet namesfor Media Type and Industry, I made it so
  that there are 2 admin models where the names can be entered:
  MediaTypeTagAdmin and IndustryTagAdmin. Here are the data object
  classes for MediaTypeTag and IndustryTag that are used by the admin
  models:

MediaTypeTag class

```
<?php
class MediaTypeTag extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'varchar(250)',
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'Name' => 'Title',
    );

    private static $field_labels = array(
        'Name'
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'PortfolioItemPages' => 'PortfolioItemPage'
    );

    // tidy up the CMS by not showing these fields
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->removeByName("PortfolioItemPages");

        return $fields;
    }

    static $default_sort = "Name ASC";
}
```

IndustryTag class

```
<?php
class IndustryTag extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'varchar(250)',
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'Name' => 'Title',
    );

    private static $field_labels = array(
        'Name'
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'PortfolioItemPages' => 'PortfolioItemPage'
    );

    // tidy up the CMS by not showing these fields
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->removeByName("PortfolioItemPages");

        return $fields;
    }


    static $default_sort = "Name ASC";
}
```

- There needs to be a page for each Portfolio Item, so I made a PortfolioItemPage type, which has 2 tabs: one for Media Type and one for Industry Type. This is so content managers can associated whatever tags they want with each Portfolio Item by checking the appropriate boxes:

PortfolioItemPage.php file:

```
    private static $db = array(
        'Excerpt' => 'Text',
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Thumbnail' => 'Image',
        'Logo' => 'Image'
    );

    private static $has_many = array(
        'PortfolioChildItems' => 'PortfolioChildItem'
    );

    private static $many_many = array(
        'MediaTypeTags' => 'MediaTypeTag',
        'IndustryTags' => 'IndustryTag'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        if ($this->ID) {
            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Media Type Tags', CheckboxSetField::create(
                'MediaTypeTags',
                'Media Type Tags',
                MediaTypeTag::get()->map()
            ));
        }

        if ($this->ID) {
            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Industry Tags', CheckboxSetField::create(
                'IndustryTags',
                'Industry Tags',
                IndustryTag::get()->map()
            ));
        }


        $gridFieldConfig = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create();

        $gridFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldBulkImageUpload());

        $gridFieldConfig->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')->setDisplayFields(array(
            'EmbedURL' => 'YouTube or SoundCloud Embed Code',
            'Thumb' => 'Thumb (135px x 135px)',
        ));

        $gridfield = new GridField(
            "ChildItems",
            "Child Items",
            $this->PortfolioChildItems(),
            $gridFieldConfig
        );

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Child Items', $gridfield);

        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextareaField("Excerpt"), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new UploadField('Thumbnail', "Thumbnail (400x x 400px)"), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new UploadField('Logo', "Logo"), "Content");

        return $fields;
    }

}
class PortfolioItemPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array (
    );

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

What I thought might be a good approach would be to use jQuery and AJAX to send the ids of the selected facets to the server:

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var industry = $('.industry');
        var media = $('.media');
        var tag = $('.tag');
        var selectedTags = "";

        tag.each(function(e) {
            $(this).bind('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $(this).addClass('selectedTag');

                if(selectedTags.indexOf($(this).text()) < 0){
                    if($(this).hasClass('media')){
                        selectedTags += + $(this).attr("id") + "," +"media;";
                    }
                    else{
                        selectedTags += + $(this).attr("id") + "," +"industry;";
                    }
                }
                sendTag(selectedTags);

            }.bind($(this)));
        });

        function sendTag(TagList){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/home/getPortfolioItemsByTags/",
                data: { tags: TagList },
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function(response) {
                var div = $('.portfolioItems');
                div.empty();
                for (var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
                    div.append(response[i].name + "<br />");
                    //return portfolio data here
                }

            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert("There was a problem processing the request.");
           });
        }
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Then on Page.php, I loop through the ids and get the corresponding PortfolioItemPage information based on the facet ids:

```
    public function getPortfolioItemsByTags(){
    //remove the last comma from the list of tag ids

    $IDs = $this->getRequest()->postVar('tags');
    $IDSplit = substr($IDs, 0, -1);

    //put the tag ids and their tag names (media or industry) into an array
    $IDListPartial = explode(";",$IDSplit);

    //This will hold the associative array of ids to types (i.e. 34 => media)
    $IDListFinal = array();
    array_walk($IDListPartial, function($val, $key) use(&$IDListFinal){
        list($key, $value) = explode(',', $val);
        $IDListFinal[$key] = $value;
    });

    //get Portfolio Items based on the tag ids and tag type
    foreach($IDListFinal as $x => $x_value) {
        if($x_value=='media'){
            $tag = MediaTypeTag::get()->byId($x);
            $portfolioItems = $tag->PortfolioItemPages();
        }
        else{
            $tag = IndustryTag::get()->byId($x);
            $portfolioItems = $tag->PortfolioItemPages();
        }

        $return = array();

        foreach($portfolioItems as $portfolioItem){
            $return[] = array(
                'thumbnail' => $portfolioItem->Thumbnail()->Link(),
                'name' => $portfolioItem->H1,
                'logo' => $portfolioItem->Logo()->Link(),
                'excerpt' => $portfolioItem->Excerpt,
                'id' => $portfolioItem->ID
            );
        }
        return json_encode($return);
    }
}
```

However, this is where I am getting stuck. While I have found some decent examples of building a PHP/MySQL faceted search outside of a CMS, I am not sure what I can modify in order to make the search work inside a CMS. That, and the examples put the facets in one table in the MySQL database whereas I have 2 (As much as I want to have just one MySQL table for both the Media Type and Industry facets, I am not sure if this is a good idea since content managers want to maintain the facet names themselves).

Are there any tutorials out there that might provide further assistance, or possibly a plugin that I have not found yet? If there is a better way to set this faceted search up, by all means, please suggest ideas. This is pretty new to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this is to filter based on the tag/media type IDs in one query (your example is doing one database query per tag/type, then appending the results).

You should be able to do something like this:

```
<?php

public function getPortfolioItemsByTags(){
    $tagString = $this->getRequest()->postVar('tags');

    // remove the last comma from the list of tag ids
    $tagString = substr($tagString, 0, -1);

    //put the tag ids and their tag names (media or industry) into an array
    $tags = explode(";", $tagString);

    //This will hold the associative array of ids to types (i.e. 34 => media)
    $filters = array(
        'media' => array(),
        'industry' => array()
    );
    array_walk($tags, function($val, $key) use(&$filters) {
        list($id, $type) = explode(',', $val);
        $filters[$type][] = $id;
    });

    $portfolioItems = PortfolioItemPage::get()->filterAny(array(
        'MediaTypeTags.ID' => $filters['media'],
        'IndustryTags.ID' => $filters['industry']
    ));

    $return = array();
    foreach($portfolioItems as $portfolioItem){
        $return[] = array(
            'thumbnail' => $portfolioItem->Thumbnail()->Link(),
            'name' => $portfolioItem->H1,
            'logo' => $portfolioItem->Logo()->Link(),
            'excerpt' => $portfolioItem->Excerpt,
            'id' => $portfolioItem->ID
        );
    }

    return json_encode($return);
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I need. I gave it a shot and it looks like it works the way I need it to. Thanks! :)